# Windows 10, View a Library grouped by tags

Tags: windows, tags

Windows 10 File Explorer, behaves differently when grouping by tags than Windows 7.
Windows 7 would show me all the contents in the subfolders of folders in the library, grouped.
Windows 10 only shows tagged elements at the root of the folders included in the library.
(I'm new to Windows 10, used 7 for years)

Comment: Windows 10 Libraries has evolved into Windows 10 Quick Access (links to files) and This PC (Documents, Music, Pictures and so on) which are real files.  Your Windows 10 Drive (Folder) is under all the above. Windows 10 is different than Windows 7 and the differences are significant.

Comment: Thank you John, but I'm interested in the functionality, not what's going on "under the hood".  Do you know if there is a way to show tagged files as I would like? (and as it were with Windows 7)

Comment: There are ways to Tag files in Windows 10. I have a refined file organization that works well with Search so I do not use Tags.   https://www.thewindowsclub.com/tags-files-windows/